# hasattr(widget, attr) vs attr in widget.keys() on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a method that enables all widges of a tk.Frame recursively, I've writen the following:

```
def enable(self, _state='normal'):
    print(self.winfo_children())
    def set_state(widget:tk.Widget):
        for ch in widget.winfo_children():
            set_state(ch)
        if hasattr(widget, 'state'):
            widget.config(state = _state)
    set_state(self)

def disable(self):
    self.enable('disable')
```

The magic should be happening on the `if hasattr(widget, 'state'):` statement, but to my surprise, buttons and radio buttons don't have the `'state'`attr.

After a while and some diging I found `widget.keys()` and now the code is working as intended using:

```
def enable(self, _state='normal'):
    print(self.winfo_children())
    def set_state(widget:tk.Widget):
        for ch in widget.winfo_children():
            set_state(ch)
        if 'state' in  widget.keys():
            widget.config(state = _state)
    set_state(self)

def disable(self):
    self.enable('disable')
```

This post has two purposes:

1. Why that is? Doesn't feel very ***Pythonic***.
2. If anyone has the same problem that I had, this posts survives, this maybe becomes an easy awnser in the future.

Comment: Tkinter widgets generally don't use attributes at all; everything is done via indexing (which is translated to `.config(()`/`.cget()`) and methods.  I would guess that this is due to the fact that Tkinter has been around a *lot* longer than the concept of properties, without which it would have been rather painful to translate attribute access to the underlying Tcl/Tk implementation.

Comment: @jasonharper yeah, I noticed that the ttk widgets work with the hasattr() methods. thank you for the clarification.